# valuations of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I saw a questions in a book (that unfortunately I don't remember it's name!) and couldn't solve it.

What are Archimedean and non-Archimedean valuations of the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For prime $p\ne 2,3$, factorize $x^3-2 \bmod p$, each irreducible factor gives a $p$-adic valuation.

Answer (score 1):

This is asking for an analogue in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ of Ostrowski's theorem for $\mathbf Q$. See Theorem 3.3 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/ostrowskinumbfield.pdf) for Ostrowski's theorem in every number field.

Comment: Thank you! @KCd